# I would like to know how to communicate with a printer in the web without going through the chrome print pop-up

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, plugins

I have a website developed in Asp.Net that will allow returning data in pdf, that I can print it.
I have an Evolis printer connected in USB mode.
I would like to know how to communicate with a printer in the web without going through the chrome print pop-up
Maybe it is necessary to develop a plugin that will be integrated into the web solution, if it is the case, I do not know with which technology it is necessary to develop it and how?
If you have any feelings to suggest I will be grateful

Comment: qztray is a pay-for product that offers this

Comment: @TKoL I know this, but the problem it's not free... 
I have to know if I can develop my own thing, I don't know what is the solution

Comment: [I saw this information through this link, but I still do not know how it will be achievable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024545/can-web-applications-detect-local-printers/55807762?noredirect=1#comment98283888_55807762)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PrintDocument class.
here is the reference from MSDN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I will see if this solution work. 
Thank you for your response